# .NET Core Logging in Console App - Detail level

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, console-application

I'm creating a console application in .NET Core 5.0 (VS 2019). I'm having trouble implementing my appsettings.json with various logging configuration. It simply does not work.

I have this at the start of the `Main()` method to configure appsettings.json:

```
var dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

var configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(dir) // Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();
```

I have also made ServiceCollection extension to configure logging in ServiceCollection:

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureApplicationLogging(this IServiceCollection @this, string appName, IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot)
{
    @this.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
    {
        loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
        loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(configurationRoot);
        loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
        loggingBuilder.AddEventLog(settings =>
        {
            settings.LogName = "Application";
            settings.SourceName = appName;
        });
    });

    return @this;
}
```

This is how I create ServiceCollection and build services:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.ConfigureApplicationLogging("MyApp", configurationRoot)
// ... add other services
var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
```

Following is my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "Console": {
      "IncludeScopes": true,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Error",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Error",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, Console's default level is set to error. I obtain logger through ServiceCollection:

`_logger = services.GetService<ILogger<MyService>>();`

Now, if I execute this code:

```
_logger.LogInformation("info");
_logger.LogError("error");
```

Both messages get printed to the console and it seems like it doesn't take settings from appsettings.json.

I've searched a lot on the internet, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Personally, I happen to use Log4Net (specifically, `NLog.Web.AspNetCore`), which works in conjunction with `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`.  As such, 1) my "Logging > LogLevel" is in `appsettings.json` (like yours), but 2) My logging sinks are defined in the separate file `nlog.config`.

Comment: OK, great. Thanks for the tip. Will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

By calling AddConsole() you are overriding the settings from the AddConfiguration() call (with defaults, since you're not providing any settings in the AddConsole call).